# Вид ссылок django

Tags: python, django

День добрый! Хотел узнать, каким способом делать ссылки вида `cards?items=30` . Чтобы пользователь введя данный url получил список 30 элементов (передача элементов уже сделана через paginator, интересует именно создание сcылок). Пока что имеется в таком виде: например `api/2` , возвращающая 2 элемента.

Мой **views.py**:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from cards.models import Card


class Api(View):
    def get(self, request, item_counts):
        cards = Card.objects.all()
        response_cards = []
        for card in cards:
            card_dict = {'url': card.url,
                         'image': card.image.path,
                         'type': card.type,
                         'preview': card.preview,
                         'category': card.category.title,
                         'title': card.title,
                         'has_button': card.has_button,
                         'button_text': card.button_text,
                         'button_url': card.button_url}
            response_cards.append(card_dict)
        elements_count = Paginator(response_cards, item_counts)
        return JsonResponse(elements_count.page(1).object_list, safe=False)
```

Мой **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from python_ru.views import Api
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/(?P<item_counts>\d{1})', Api.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, про что ты спрашиваешь, это передача `GET` параметра, и этот параметр не нужно принимать в `url`, делается это так:

urlpatterns :

```
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', Api.as_view()),
```

view:

```
class Api(View):
    def get(self, request, item_counts):
        cards = Card.objects.all()
        response_cards = []
        page = 1
        if self.request.GET.get('page'):
            page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        for card in cards:
            card_dict = {'url': card.url,
                         'image': card.image.path,
                         'type': card.type,
                         'preview': card.preview,
                         'category': card.category.title,
                         'title': card.title,
                         'has_button': card.has_button,
                         'button_text': card.button_text,
                         'button_url': card.button_url}
            response_cards.append(card_dict)
        elements_count = Paginator(response_cards, item_counts)
        return JsonResponse(elements_count.page(page).object_list, safe=False)
```

templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'api' %}?page=30">Show 30 items</a>
```

Во `view` может быть не очень лаконично, но так делал я, и оно работало :)

Если же ты хочешь принять этот параметр в `url`, тогда оставь `urlpatterns` как есть, а с `page` сделай так:

```
        page = 1
        if self.kwargs['page']:
            page = self.kwargs['page']
```

и тогда в шаблоне:

```
<a href="{% url 'api' 30 %}">Show 30 items</a>
```